How can I prevent Task.Run and Parallel.ForEach from using the "outer" thread?
My "outer" code running under a thread (obviously). That outer code calls Parallel.ForEach and/or Task.Run, and the outer thread also gets used inside those methods.
Consider this code:
public void MyMethod()
{
  // This thread is FOO

  Parallel.ForEach(someCollection, c => {
    // FOO sometimes get used in here
  });

  Task.Run(() => {
    // FOO also sometimes gets used in here
  })

  // This is still FOO
}

I have documented that thread FOO is also appearing inside the work being done in Parallel.ForEach and Task.Run.
I do not want this. How I do force these methods to use "fresh" threads? Ideally, how do I get them to destroy those threads when they're done?
The reason is: I have some [ThreadStatic] variables that need to be isolated to a specific task, then they need to disappear, and they should not be shared. Each thread has to be... "clean"

Why? Why do you care? Why do you want them dead? Also: Tasks are not threads.

The Task.Run call is fire-and-forget. Is this intentional? Don't you want to .Wait() or await the task?

@Fildor as far as I can see, the OP has not claimed that tasks are threads.

Not directly, no. But reading the question made me just reiterate.

I have some [ThreadStatic] variables that need to be isolated to a specific task, then they need to disappear, and they should be shared.

Related: Is it possible always to force a new thread with Task?

It looks like you are mixing up tasks and threads. If you need a Local specific to a certain operation then you should use AsyncLocal, but I would strongly recommend you find another method, such as Parallel's localInit parameter.
